# boost::beast - auto reconnect (Websocket, c++)

Tags: c++, boost-beast

how do you reconnect your websocket if the connection fails/breaks?
I'm currently using the example async_client:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/example/http/client/async/http_client_async.cpp

The idea is to have a thread that checks every 10-20 seconds if the handshake/connection is still "Open" - - if not we would reconnect using the same URI.

I'm open for any suggestions.